# UDP Broadcast or IP Multicast?

Tags: network-programming, broadcast

If you had to implement a network broadcast, would you use UDP broadcast or IP multicast in a new application? Why?

What are the benefits and drawbacks you encountered with either method? (Especially concerning problems with VPNs, different subnets, various routers etc.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Multicast has the drawback that it is not well supported by routers and NAT.  If all of your clients are on the same network with only simple bridges, multicast works great and avoids the overhead of broadcast addressing for machines that are not part of the group.  If the routers support IGMP and properly propagate the TTL it can work on local networks.  There have been attempts to do multicast across the Internet, such as [Mbone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbone), with various levels of success.  Most of them use some sort of tunnel to get around bridges and non-compliant routers.

One caveat for multicast packets, however, is if there are any WiFi connections [the access point will use the slowest possible bit rate](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/3433451) for the multicast packets and requires acks from all clients, even those who are not part of the multicast group.  There are also drawbacks for non-participating clients and battery life.

Comment: The article about use of multicast over 802.11 is really interesting, however it's from nearly ten years ago. Does anyone have a reference that explains whether this is still as much of an issue in practice for newer versions of the 802.11 family of standards?

Comment: The article is now no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of which is most appropriate depends on the nature of the application and the configuration of the networks over which it's to be run - there's no hard or fast rules.

I therefore wouldn't enforce either - I'd allow configuration of the broadcast address.

If the user configures something in the 224.0.0.0/4 range then it's multicast, otherwise it's broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

The way multicast behaves is almost, but not entirely, unlike every other type of network traffic.  Your systems and network administrators won't thank you for forcing it on them.  It's often voodoo, and IMO best avoided if you can.

Comment: You should spill the beans here:  multicast forces the network node to interrupt the higher level IP stack and see if any application is interested in the received multicast packet.  Every time on every node on every multicast send.  So, that's why net admins hate it.